# Moment getting date attributes mistakenly

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use MomentJS to support dates handling in my application. However, I'm facing a problem with date manipulation.

The files are loaded in this order:

```
<script src="/javascripts/modules/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/modules/moment/moment-timezone.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/modules/moment/moment-timezone-data.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/modules/moment/moment-with-langs.min.js"></script>
```

Now in somepart of my JS code I change the moment language to FR or PT.

```
moment.lang('fr');
```

Both languages validade a date as `"DD/MM/YYYY"` instead of american pattern. So I expect moment
to validate a date following the country date pattern passed.

Then `12/10/2014` must be: **day** (12), **month** (09), **year** (2014), but it is returning always american pattern instead of the correct one.

I'm getting the date properties as:

```
console.log("DAY: " + moment(textDate).date());
console.log("MONTH: " + moment(textDate).month());
console.log("YEAR: " + moment(textDate).year());
```

where `textDate` is my date taken from a text input.

**## EDIT ##**

I know I can pass the pattern to Moment. I.e:

```
moment(textDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

In the case of my application I'm using like this:

```
moment(textDate, '<%=lingua.general.time.pDate%>');
```

However, it suppose to work automatically, don't it? Of course if you already have needed language packages as well. So the previous way I mentioned before should Works, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't pass any formatting arguments, moment will let your *browser* do the parsing (with the exception of a full ISO timestamp).

To tell moment to do the parsing, and to use the localized short date format associated with the language, pass an `L` as the format string:

```
moment(textDate, 'L')
```

See in the docs:

- Parsing using [#String+Format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)
- The [display formats](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). Scroll down to "Localized formats".  (The parser uses the same format strings)

Also, not related to your question, but moment-with-langs already includes a copy of moment.js, so you don't need both scripts.

Comment: Ok, Matt. It worked out for me. I thought that when you specified a language, it automatically recognize the pattern. I was naive. Now my problem is with "isValid" function, but this is a subject for another topic.

Comment: Easy mistake to make.  Glad you asked, I'm sure someone else will find this useful as well!